# Using variables in regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Python amateur here:

I'm just playing around with regular expressions, and I've come across this:

```
import re

while True:
    userInput = input('Type in your string here: ')
    regexInput = input('Enter Regex pattern here:')

    testRegex = re.compile([^regexInput])
    testMO = testRegex.search(userInput)
    print(testMO.group())
```

Basically, I want my regex to match everything except the pattern I've specified through regexInput. However, I am getting syntax errors from this code. I thought that putting a carrot right after the opening bracket of a character class, it means that Python will search for everything other than what's in the bracket?
I'm doing the last project of Chapter 7 in Automate the Boring Things.
How can I get my code to match everything other than what is typed in regexInput?

Someone told me this:

> regex expects string so you have to create string:

`"[^" + regexInput +"]" or "[^{}]".format(regexInput)`

I don't really fully understand this reply, especially the second part of the answer. Just to test out what he said, I used this code:

```
import re

while True:
    userInput = input('Type in your string here: ')
    regexInput = input('Enter Regex pattern here:')

    testRegex = re.compile(regexInput)
    testMO = testRegex.search(userInput).group()
    print(testMO)
```

Which gave me an output of:

```
Type in your string here: Here lies Batman.
Enter Regex pattern here:Batman
Batman
Type in your string here:
```

Doesn't this mean that the regex also took a variable, and made it work? So I'm kind of confused as to what this other person said, as it seems to contradict his statement of '`regex` expects a string'.

Comment: Short answer: `input` returns a string. Strings are different from literal code, which is what was throwing the syntax error.

Comment: It doesn't contradict the statement.  `input()` returns a string.  Your two code examples are not equivalent.  There are several ways to create a string in Python, putting literal text *inside quotes* is one, reading from an input stream (using `input()`) is another.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[^regexInput]` is not a syntactically valid Python expression.  It looks like you are trying to create the string consisting of the characters `[^`, followed by the value of the variable `regexInput`, followed by the character `]`.  One way to write this in Python is: `'[^' + regexInput + ']'`.